# is it possible to have android navigation drawer with grid view i.e. grid view inside navigation drawer?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Please I want to implement Grid View(2 column) in navigation drawer of my app.
I want to know that is it possible?
if yes, then can you give me steps to follow to get desired result?

Comment: please check this links it will helps you,

1)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339086/gridview-and-navigation-drawer-not-working-together-in-android

2)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890314/gridview-is-not-shown-in-an-example-with-navigation-drawer

Comment: 1st one is trying to implement grid view when he click on nav drawer item?

Comment: @Tushar yeah! i want to have grid view like note ,snapshot,audio , attach given in that question , can u tell me how that can be done?  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have any layout in your navigation drawer you want. The `DrawerLayout` is just a special wrapper that uses its first child as the normal content and the second child as the navigation drawer that can be swiped in and out. That second child can be any `View` or `ViewGroup` you like, including `GridView`, `ListView`, `LinearLayout` or whatever.

Comment: can you give me source code or link to the example where second child of drawer layout is other than list view ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using Android Studio. The following worked for me:

1) Create a new **Navigation Drawer Activity**.

2) Several layout files will be created for you, including a *content_main.xml*. Place your `<GridView>` XML in the *content_main.xml* file.

3) Do also create the relevant files for the GridView like the adapter class and an XML for the GridView item layout.