# Drawer menu using Collection View in ios

Tags: ios, navigation-drawer

I want to design the drawer menu using custom collection view like android drawer with gridview.Is there any way to design the drawer like android

- (Note:- Ask question in android refer below link
  ([is it possible to have android navigation drawer with grid view i.e. grid view inside navigation drawer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29469041/is-it-possible-to-have-android-navigation-drawer-with-grid-view-i-e-grid-view-i)) Same like this can we do in ios.)

Answer (score 0):

For this you have create one viewcontroller which contain uicollectionview. this is work as side bar controller, Now add another controller as childviewcontroller with changing frame with animations.

Comment: Hi Dheeraj thanks for reply
Can u please suggest any example or code snipets.

Comment: No there is no any exmaple for that