# gridview and navigation drawer error

Tags: android, gridview, navigation-drawer

I had copy and edit the codes according to the answer from  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21339086/gridview-and-navigation-drawer-not-working-together-in-android) post. But when I run the simulator, I got a runtime error saying "Unfortunately App Has Stopped". However, my logcat is showing a different error from the post.

I had tried clean project/rebuilt project/invalidate cache but still can't get the app to work.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.app.myapplication4/com.app.myapplication4.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.app.myapplication4.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 56 of my code is:

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

My machine have jdk 7, Android Studio 1.0.2, Android Support Library 21.0.3, Android Support Repository 11 and my AVD is running on API level 16 x86.

Comment: Are you using Activity or ActionBarActivity?

Comment: I had just copy the code from that post. The codes are as follows:
MainActivity extends Activity
PlanetFragment extends Fragment (within main activity)